# jquery formatCurrency plugin breaks standard change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `formatCurrency` plugin
[Here](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/)

however, when i add the location of script it breaks other code.  for example, below, the `change()` doesn't fire.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js" </script>
    < script >
        $(function() {
            $('#customerType').change(function() {
                alert('hi');
            });
        });
</script>
<select name='customerType' id='customerType'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='happy'>Happy</option>
    <option value='sad'>Sad</option>
</select>
```

if i remove `<script src="jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js"</script>`
it works fine.

the js file loads fine.

Comment: aren't you missing ">" ... <script src="jquery.formatCurrency-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: i love it when its an easy fix.

Comment: If that answered your question, can you please add it as an answer? And accept it?